# Jenkins - trigger build when Github PR is closed or merged

Tags: github, jenkins, terraform

I am using Jenkins with Github pull request builder plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

It's fine to trigger the build when the PR is open or update but I need a way to trigger when the PR is closed or merged.

I use Terraform to launch a bunch of servers so I need the event or condition to terminate the stack after the PR is closed/merged.

Seems like most of the plugins only be trigger by open/update event on Github PR.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by two methods:

1) Either by a webhook. This requires your jenkins to have a public endpoint or some public endpoint (could be a proxy) via which github can post to your jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-ManualMode

2) If a public endpoint is not available, then poll the repo every minute as a workaround.

http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html

Please note that in bigger setups, poll may have some performance implications. (I have been using it for years without any problems in smaller setups).

https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/jenkins-poll-scm-the-nightmare-for-performance/

Comment: At the end, we implement a cron job that checks the status of PR and trigger Terraform code. Works fine for now.